# A question on mean free path of gases in a container

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinetic-theory

Two identical containers kept at the same temperature carry the same gas with different molecular mean free paths l1 and l2.  the gas from the first container is completely transferred in to the second container at the same temperature. What is the molecular resultant mean free path in the second container?

Does it have something to do with equating the initial number densities of molecules to the final number densities?

please help!

Comment: Nice that you weren't tempted to answer quickly :)